# From Decimal to Binary system

Tags: javascript, binary

I want to make an easy website because I want to learn javascript. The website will have just one (number) input named "number". After clicking on submit button the website will convert the number from decimal to binary system and show the answer.

This is the javascript part that should convert the number and show the answer in a div with ID = result:

```js
var selectedNumber = document.getElementByName("number").value;
var k = [];
var a = 0;
var b = 1;

while (selectedNumber > 1){
  if(selectedNumber%2 < 1){
    k=k.append(a);
    selectedNumber = Math.floor(selectedNumber/2);
  }
  else{
    k=k.append(b);
    selectedNumber = Math.floor(selectedNumber/2);
  }
}
k=k.append(b);

for i in reversed(k){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHETML = i;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience using javascript and this code doesn't work. I've made a similar program in python and based this code on that in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected code:
Tip - Whenever you have to glue two numbers to form a string make sure to do 1 + "" +2

```
var selectedNumber = 105;//document.getElementByName("number").value;
var k = [];
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
var output = '';

while (selectedNumber > 1){
  if(selectedNumber%2 < 1){
    k=k+""+a;
    selectedNumber = Math.floor(selectedNumber/2);
  }
  else{
    k=k+""+b;
    selectedNumber = Math.floor(selectedNumber/2);
  }
}
k=k+""+b;

console.log(k);
//document.getElementByName("number").value = k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `toString(2)` method.

```js
let a  =7
console.log(a.toString(2))
```

I have made some minor changes to your code. removed redundant lines. i am appending values to a front of string instead of an array ( which you later reverse and join).

```js
function handle(){
  let selectedNumber = document.getElementById("number").value;
let k = '',a = 0, b = 1;

while (selectedNumber > 1){
  if(selectedNumber%2 < 1){
    k= a+k
  }
  else{
    k=b+k
  }
  selectedNumber = Math.floor(selectedNumber/2);
}
k=b+k;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = k;
}
```

```css
#result{
  color: green;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<input id='number' placeholder='enter value'></input>
<button onClick=handle()>Convert to binary</button> 

<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a whole lot simpler than that. The [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method takes an optional argument that can be used to convert a number to a different numerical base system, like its binary, octal or hex values.

Prepending the input's value with `+`, forces the input's value to become a number.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let number = +document.querySelector("input").value; // Convert input into a string
  console.clear();
  console.log("The decimal: " + number + " converted to a binary is: "  + number.toString(2));
  console.log("The decimal: " + number + " converted to an octal is: "  + number.toString(8));
  console.log("The decimal: " + number + " converted to a hex is: "  + number.toString(16));  
});
```

```html
<input><button>Convert!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this goal, actually you can forget all your code and simple use [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString). It takes an optional argument of the `base` you want to use for convert the `number` to `string`.

**Example:**

```js
const convert = () =>
{
    let number = document.getElementById("iNumber").value;
    binNumber = Number.parseInt(number, 10).toString(2);
    document.getElementById("dRes").innerHTML = binNumber;
};
```

```html
<input id="iNumber" type="number">
<button id="btnToBinary" onclick="convert()">
  Convert To Binary
</button>
<div id="dRes"></div>
```